# using arctext jquery plugin to create dynamic arc of text using range tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I like the create arctext dynamically so I used arctext jquery plugin and I used the range html tag to select the arc or curve in the text.

This is my html code

```
<label>Curve:</label>
<input type="range" name="value" id="value" min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
<p  id="textvalue"> I wanna to be curve</p>
```

javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#value").change(function () {
    var newValue = $('#value').val();
    changetext(newValue);
  });
  function changetext(newValue){
    console.log(newValue);
    var pos;
    if(newValue>0)
      pos=1;
    else{
      pos=-1;
      $("#textvalue").hide();
      $("#textvalue").show().arctext({radius:newValue, dir: pos});
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

But this code work for the first drag. But later on it keeps remains unchanged. The range value is keep on changing which I came to know by console.log.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to have the $("textvalue").hide() stuff outside the braces of the if statement. Also the slider goes negative and the text only takes positive values. I took a look at this and the  only way I could get it to work was to completely remove the element and replace it with a the different radius so,

```
$(function(){
$("#value").change(function () {
 var newValue = $('#value').val();
 changetext(newValue);
});
function changetext(newValue){
  console.log(newValue);
  var pos;
  if(newValue>0)
   pos=1;
  else{
   pos=-1;
  }
  var text = $("#textvalue").text();
  $("#textvalue").remove();
  $('body').append('<p id="textvalue">'+ text +'</p>');
  $("#textvalue").arctext({radius:Math.abs(newValue), dir: pos});
 }
});
```